# aws lambda function using serverless template of asp.net core

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, triggers, asp.net-core-webapi, aws-serverless

I don't have enough knowledge of aws but my company asked me to do a job which I guess is what AWS Lambda does perfectly. The requirement is I have to create a service that has an endpoint that needs to be called twice a day. The approach I followed is I created a serverless web API through visual studio and created API gateway endpoint for each endpoint. Then added a trigger through cloud watch events to run it twice a day but whenever the function is triggered I get this error.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.: NullReferenceException
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )
```

Comment: If are you invoking the Lambda function written in .NET using a cloudwatch event, why use API Gateway? You can invoke the Lambda function directly from a cloudwatch event.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue and could fix it recently.

If you use Lambda with ASP.NET Core, you should have `LambdaEntryPoint` class to handle all the requests.
Try to override `MarshallRequest` method in this class, add logging and see what you have in `apiGatewayRequest` parameter. The code can look something like this:

```cs
protected override void MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Request path: {apiGatewayRequest.Path}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Request path parameters: {apiGatewayRequest.PathParameters}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Request body: {apiGatewayRequest.Body}");
    LambdaLogger.Log($"Request request context: {apiGatewayRequest.RequestContext}");
    base.MarshallRequest(features, apiGatewayRequest, lambdaContext);
}
```

In my case, all these values were nulls. The reason for it was in using Amazon EventBridge for keeping Lambda online to avoid a cold start. If you also use EventBridge, try to configure the request properly. If not, you can try to update `MarshalRequest` the following way:

```cs
protected override void MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
    if(apiGatewayRequest.RequestContext == null) //Or other property
    {
        return;
    }

    base.MarshallRequest(features, apiGatewayRequest, lambdaContext);
}
```

Comment: Not using Amazon EventBridge but values are null. Did anyone manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I had the same problem. Grigory Zhadko’s answer helped me a lot by knowing which method I should overwrite. `LambdaEntryPoint` requires for any other process to instantiate an `ApiGatewayProxiRequest` object manually (for example, `eventBridge`). The configuration I implemented to fix the problem is as follows.

```cs
protected override void MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
    var endpoint = "my/endpoint";

    if (apiGatewayRequest != null && apiGatewayRequest?.RequestContext == null)
    {
        apiGatewayRequest.Path = $"/{endpoint}";
        apiGatewayRequest.Resource = $"/{endpoint}";
        apiGatewayRequest.HttpMethod = "ANY METHOD";
        apiGatewayRequest.RequestContext = new APIGatewayProxyRequest.ProxyRequestContext
        {
            Path = $"/path/{endpoint}", // your path request
            Identity = new APIGatewayProxyRequest.RequestIdentity
            {
                ClientCert = new APIGatewayProxyRequest.ProxyRequestClientCert
                {
                    Validity = new APIGatewayProxyRequest.ClientCertValidity()
                }
            },
            ResourcePath = $"/{basePath}{eventEntpoint}",
            HttpMethod = "ANY METHOD",
            Authorizer = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerContext()
        };
    }

    base.MarshallRequest(features, apiGatewayRequest, lambdaContext);
}
```